# Run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Tags: npm, installation, audit, fix-protocol

When I try to compile project, getting:

```
found 2860 vulnerabilities (2122low, 19 moderate, 726 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

This comes from npm install and npm run ng build --prod in the angular project.
I currently have a

- Angular CLI: 9.1.1
- Node: 12.16.2
- OS: win32 x64

How can I solve this?
Can we upgrade the project in a easy way or should I downgrade my Angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `npm audit fix` in the terminal, inside the project. This should fix your problem.